# Make sure button gets pressed if checked radio button change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bug on my website... There are 2 radio button's, one for U.S and one for Canada. U.S Shipping cost is less expensive than Canada's on my website but a user from Canada can update shipping preferences to U.S which is less costly than Canada and then the user can go back to Canada's option without pressing update shipping button and go to the next page. This way they can get by by getting cheaper shipping. What can be the easiest work around from that? I was thinking of a javascript that would detect if the user has changed shipping options.

Here's what I have for the HTML part:

```
<input type='radio' id='1' name='shipping' value='1'/>&nbsp;United States&nbsp;
<input type='radio' id='2' name='shipping' value='2' checked="checked"/>&nbsp;Canada&nbsp;
<input type='submit' name='UpdateShipping' id='UpdateShipping' value='Update Shipping' />
```

You can see it in action [here](http://asiraj.com/checkout.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('input[name="shipping"]').change(function(){ //change event of radio button
   $('#jcartUpdateShipping').trigger('click'); //click button
});
```

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

---

**Updated After OP's comment**

[.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$(document).delegate('input[name="shipping"]','change',function(){ //change event of radio button
   $('#jcartUpdateShipping').trigger('click'); //click button
});
```

---

```
// jQuery 1.4.3+
$( elements ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );
// jQuery 1.7+
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

---

Use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: It doesn't work :/ I think I will have to get the Update Shipping button to press if the radio button changes

Comment: Doesn't work for me on my website :/ Can you provide me with a jsfiddle working demo so I can try to figure out why it is not working on my website

Comment: @iheartbreakz where have you added the code i have written in your page i can't find it ?

Comment: @iheartbreakz it's not there i just checked . Please check again .

Comment: Sorry, I edited that comment... I added it on the wrong page... This code works fine! One question... this means I will have to get rid of the update shipping button... Is there any way I can make a check on submit if the radio buttons changed?

Comment: @iheartbreakz you can hide the update setting button using `display:none` or you can work on change of radio button for update setting instead of button .